# Configure Webpack HMR with touching webpack-dev-server from remote (ngrok)

Tags: hot-module-replacement

I'm trying to configure Webpack *Hot Module Replacement* to work with a remote server.

I'm building an application on Salesforce.com platform and want to configure internal application page to get all necessary files from my local machine using *ngrok* and *webpack-dev-server*. And the actual result is the same behavior of HMR - replace changed modules using *socketio*. I use [angular-webpack2-starter](https://github.com/qdouble/angular-webpack2-starter) seed project to test it just from *ngrok*. But when I   open the page from *ngrok* endpoint and update some module the connection with HMR is lost.

[Logs screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCBVu.png)